# laravel undefined variable: itinerary

Tags: php, laravel

I can't seem to find the variable **itinerary** from my **update** function in my controller. What seems to be the problem for this?

Error says: **Undefined variable: itinerary (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\project_name\resources\views\Agent\edit.blade.php)**

#### AgentsController update function

```
public function update(Request $request, $p_id){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'packageName' => 'required',
        'adultPrice' => 'required',
        'childPrice' => 'required',
        'infantPrice' => 'required',
        'excessPrice' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required',
        'inclusions' => 'required',
        'additionalInfo' => 'required',
        'reminders' => 'required',
        'photo' => 'required',
        'tags' => 'required',
        'noOfDays' => 'required',
        'day' => 'required',
        'time' => 'required',
        'destination' => 'required'
    ]);

    $packages = Packages::find($p_id);
    $packages->packageName = $request->input('packageName');
    $packages->adultPrice = $request->input('adultPrice');
    $packages->childPrice = $request->input('childPrice');
    $packages->infantPrice = $request->input('infantPrice');
    $packages->excessPrice = $request->input('excessPrice');
    $packages->type = $request->input('type');
    $packages->inclusions = $request->input('inclusions');
    $packages->additionalInfo = $request->input('additionalInfo');
    $packages->reminders = $request->input('reminders');
    $packages->photo = $request->input('photo');
    $packages->tags = $request->input('tags');
    $packages->save();

    $itinerary = Itinerary::find($p_id);
    if($itinerary->p_id == $packages->p_id){
    $itinerary->noOfDays = $request->input('noOfDays');
    $itinerary->day = $request->input('day');
    $itinerary->time = $request->input('time');
    $itinerary->destination = $request->input('destination');
    $itinerary->save();

    return redirect('Agent/Packages')->with('success', 'Updated');
    }
}
```

#### edit.blade.php where the error is located

```
{{!!Form::open(array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'method' => 'post', 'action' => array('AgentsController@update', $packages->p_id, $itinerary->p_id)))!!}}
```

#### Itinerary.php Model

```
<?php
   namespace App;

   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

   class Itinerary extends Model{
      public $fillable = [
        'p_id',
        'noOfDays',
        'day',
        'time',
        'destination'
   ];

   protected $primaryKey = 'i_id';
   }
?>
```

#### Edit function

```
public function edit($p_id){
   $packages = Packages::find($p_id);
   $itinerary = Itinerary::find($p_id);

   return View::make('\Agent\Edit', ['packages' => $packages, 'itineraries' => $itinerary]);
}
```

Comment: Where is the controller method that renders the `edit.blade.php` view?

Comment: Updated: check the last part of my question. I believe it has something to do with the return function passing both tables and variables. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: `{{!!` should be either `{{` either `{!!`.

Answer (score 2):

The way you pass the data is wrong.

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#passing-data-to-views)

There are few ways you can pass. Examples :

1 -
`return View::make('Agent.edit', ['packages' => $packages, 'itinerary' => $itinerary]);`

2 - `return View::make('Agent.edit')->with(['packages' => $packages, 'itinerary' => $itinerary]);`

3 - `return View::make('Agent.edit')->with('packages', $packages)->with('itinerary', $itinerary);`

Comment: Updated my return to that, it's still giving the same error.

Comment: @lexeezy Updated the answer with few ways. Can you try and let me know. Should work

Comment: It's still not working. Btw, the table name is itineraries, not itinerary

Comment: @lexeezy As I see database name doesn't matter. `itinerary` is undefined in `Agent\edit.blade.php` means when you return the view your not passing the `itinerary` variable.

Comment: @lexeezy Double check the name. If `'test' => $itinerary` then edit.blade.php should able to access `$test`. Array key name matches the variable name in the blade.

Comment: Noted, thanks for that. Now, I'm getting a new error which is `Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\project_name\resources\views\Agent\edit.blade.php)`

Comment: @lexeezy  Probably the object `$packages` or `$itinerary` in the controller is empty.

Comment: How to distinguish that it's empty in the controller? In the database, it isn't empty.

Comment: @lexeezy `find` retrieves model by its primary key. I guess `Itinerary::find($p_id);` returns null. Try getting itinerary using `where` function.

Comment: It's now working but I set the p_id in itineraries model to primaryKey. Is this a good practice at all?

Comment: @lexeezy Hey I don't think its good idea to make `p_id` primary key in itinerary. You can use `where` function. Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent for more. Also if this solves your question, please up vote & accept the answer. For more helps you can ask more question.

Comment: I don't have the idea on how to do it? Will you enlighten me? It will be a big help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your edit.blade.php, try remplacing your $itinerary variable by $itineraries (plural).

Comment: Changed everything to plural, still giving this kind of error: `Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\project_name\resources\views\Agent\edit.blade.php)`

Comment: Are you sure there is an itinerary with the Id you sent? You should add à check in the edit function to make sure both $packages and $itinerary haren't null

Comment: Yes, the id that I'm trying to get both exists in itineraries and packages. The p_id came from the packages table (which is primary key) and the p_id in the itineraries is a foreign key.

Comment: I'm pretty sure find is used to find an object with the id you gave it as primary key. You need to tell it to look for the right field.